# Regular expression in Rstudio's "Find in files"

Tags: r, rstudio

**How do I use regular expressions in Rstudio's "Find in files"?**

Searching for literal numbers work just fine:

[image]

But when trying to use a regular expression to find a number I can't:

[image]

The documentation does not mention which type of regex is needed:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200710523-Navigating-Code

So maybe I am using a wrong flavor of regex?

Comment: You can use my package **findInFiles**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RStudio documentation is (to be kind) sorely lacking a reference describing the regex syntax that is supported within RStudio find and replace dialogs.

However, in answer to your question about how to find numeric digits, either of the following works in the "Find in Files" dialog with "Regular expression" option ticked:

```
[0-9]
[[:digit:]]
```

Unfortunately as you found `\d` does not work. In fact, on my current version* `\d` simply finds the letter 'd' or 'D'.

`\s` works as expected so perhaps `\d` not working is a bug in RStudio?

---

*RStudio version I'm using:

```
Version 1.1.463 – © 2009-2018 RStudio, Inc.
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio Safari/538.1 Qt/5.4.0
```

Answer (score 5):

RStudio uses POSIX Basic Regular Expressions for its "Find in files" functionality (because it is using grep under the hood).

Comment: Some links to save future readers 5 seconds of Googling:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions